# Combining results in Powershell

Tags: powershell

I have a powershell function that gets information from Active directory.  It will send an email and the body of the email will contain whatever group is associated with that email address. As you can see below test@email.com is listed twice. Rather sending 2 emails to test@email.com, I would rather send one e-mail with both groups in the body. How can I achieve this? Thanks

```
email               group
test@email.com      number1
test@email.com      number2
notet@email.com     number1
hello@email.com     number3

(Get-ADUser -Identity lbono –Properties MemberOf | Select MemberOf).MemberOf | Get-ADGroup -Properties ManagedBy | Select Name, ManagedBy, Distinguishedname, GroupCategory |

Where-Object {
$_.Distinguishedname -notlike "*Unity*" -and $_.Distinguishedname -notlike "*DynastyGroups*" -and $_.name -notlike "*Technical Library*" }|
ForEach-Object {
If ($_.ManagedBy) {
$result = New-Object PSObject
Add-Member -input $result NoteProperty 'Group Name' $_.Name
Add-Member -input $result NoteProperty 'Managed By' ((Get-ADUser -Identity $_.ManagedBy).givenName + ' ' + ((Get-ADUser -Identity $_.ManagedBy).surName))
Add-Member -input $result NoteProperty 'Email' (Get-ADUser -Identity $_.ManagedBy -Properties mail).Mail
Add-Member -input $result NoteProperty 'Group Type' $_.GroupCategory
Write-Output $result
}

} | select 'Group Name','Managed By','Email','Group Type' | sort 'Managed By'
```

Comment: What format is the information returned in? Is that just a pure String object?

Comment: the format is just your typical sorted Powershell output.

Comment: Please supply the script(remove sensitive information if any).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this is perfect use-case for Group-Object cmdlet.
Snippet that shows how you can take advantage of it:

```
@'
email,group
test@email.com,number1
test@email.com,number2
notet@email.com,number1
hello@email.com,number3
'@ | ConvertFrom-Csv | Group-Object email | foreach {
    "To: {0} Body: {1}" -f 
        $_.Name, 
        (($_.Group | foreach { $_.group }) -join ', ')
}
```

Alternative: use hashtables:

```
$mails = @{}
@'
email,group
test@email.com,number1
test@email.com,number2
notet@email.com,number1
hello@email.com,number3
'@ | ConvertFrom-Csv | ForEach-Object {
    if ($mails.ContainsKey($_.email)) {
        $mails."$($_.email)" += ", $($_.group)"
    } else {
        $mails."$($_.email)" = $_.group
    }
}

$mails.GetEnumerator() | ForEach-Object {
    "To: {0} Body: {1}" -f $_.Key, $_.Value
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Since nothing is specified I assume that your function `My-Function` returns an array of objects, with one object per email+group combination.
Also, I assume that Email and Group is stored in properties called `email` and `group`.

```
My-Function | Group-Object Email | % { 
    New-Object psobject -Property @{
        Email = $_.Name
        Groups = ($_.Group | select -ExpandProperty Group)
    }
}
```